Run a command in a specific Command Prompt window using its Process ID
Is there a way to run a command in a specific Command Prompt window using its Process ID?
$command = "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" 
$ID = (Start-Process -FilePath $Command -PassThru).Id 
Write-Host $ID 
$command = "mycommandgoeshere"
$process = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId=$ID"
$process.InvokeMethod("Create", $command)

However, it is failing with the error 
NotSpecified: Exception calling "InvokeMethod" with "2" argument(s): "Invalid method "
I'm looking for a way to run commands on a remote server in the same command window. Thank you!

You don't need CMD at all to run commands on a remote machine at all, you know that, right? Regardless of that - why did you add the tags for different PowerShell versions? Are you asking for a specific version? If not you should remove these tags. Thanks in advance.

@Olaf Thank you for your response. I removed the version specific powershell tags. Here is what I'm trying to achieve. Octopus is the orchestrator

Run a ps1 command on a remote server (Step1)
Execute a bunch of other stuff, deployments etc
Run another ps1 from the same window as Step1


I don't know octopus ... why you need to run it from the same window? If you need to run stuff in sequence just run it in sequence.  ‍♂️

We are trying to deploy to a VMWare capture machine. It involves running Start-AVAppCapture command, install the application and run Stop-AVTask to create the VHD file. But Stop-AVTask should be run from the same session that ran Start-AVAppCapture

I have no experiences with VMWare but I don't see the issue. You can run whatever you want from within the same script/session.  ‍♂️  ... I guess I'm missing something.

What do you mean "from the same window"? Octopus isn't looking at a screen...

@MathiasR.Jessen From the same ps1 session
